# BitClix Publisher Iframe Unable to Connect?

Tags: html, url, iframe, bitcoin

I recently signed up with BitClix (http://bitclix.com) to try out ads on my website. I set up a test page using the code they provided (shown below).

However, every time I load the page, it says FireFox is "Unable to connect" to ads.bcsyndication.com.

When I go directly to the URL in my web browser, the ads show up fine. What might be causing this?

Code given by BitClix:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border: 0; width: 728px; height: 90px;" src="//ads.bcsyndication.com/get.php?s=9056"></iframe>
```

My test page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ACNET - Support Us!</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hey there, click on this ad to help us out! ;)
</p>
<iframe scrolling="no" style="border: 0; width: 728px; height: 90px;" src="//ads.bcsyndication.com/get.php?s=9056"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the // to http:// and still, Firefox was unable to connect.

Comment: It works in firefox for me. Do you have this test code hosted on a website?

Comment: I thought it might be because my website is using https, so I tried it on a domain with simply http. This time, nothing showed up at all! :(

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is...

My webserver is running with an SSL certificate in https. Because the ad website only has http, Firefox considers the iframe to be "mixed active content" and blocks it.

On a normal webserver in http with no certificates, it works perfectly fine.

TLDR; http iframes are a nono on https websites